# Update Table with a valuable ( Sqlite)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

i can't insert or update with a valuable.
i don't know syntax

```
 self.Value = self.Pass.text()
 Database.ram.execute('''INSERT INTO Pass VALUE (?)''',self.Value)
```

thanks

Comment: My advise for you is to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: try str(self.Value) in place of self.Value

Comment: there is a lot of code missing for us to understand... but you probably need to call `commit()` on the database connection.

Comment: I read docs , but there is nothing ! 

i really just want know how add a valuable into database

Comment: i catch a value from user and want to send it to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much of your code to go on but I would use the following SQLite statement:

```
Database.ram.execute('UPDATE table SET column = ?', (self.Value))
conn.commit() # with conn = sqlite3.connect('db name')
```

And if you want to insert:

```
Database.ram.execute('INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES(?)', (self.Value))
conn.commit() # with conn = sqlite3.connect('db name')
```

Comment: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.

this error !
i only have one column , Password ! i get password and want to send it to database

Comment: try using (self.Value, )